# Finding the root of a transcendental equation involving $\cosh$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

How would I find the value of $a$ from the below equation:

$$a\cosh(\frac a{50})-a=20$$

I have tried doing it by turning the $\cosh$ into its respective exponential form but I ended up in a dead end in the rearranging. Is there an alternative, simpler way?

Comment: There is no way to find a closed-form solution, since you get an equation which has a combination of an exponential function and a linear function. Your best bet is probably for a numerical approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, there is no way to get an analytical solution to find $a$ such that $$a\cosh(\frac a{50})-a=20$$ and some numerical method would be required (Newton method will be the simplest).

Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(a)=a\cosh(\frac a{50})-a-20$$Plotting it reveals that the solution is between $40$ and $50$; so, let us start using $a_0=50$ which will ensure that the solution will be reached without any overshoot (by Darboux theorem).

Below are given the successive iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & a_n \\
 0 & 50.000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 45.836520166672586528 \\
 2 & 45.378402530655470850 \\
 3 & 45.373218337983547755 \\
 4 & 45.373217680246110845 \\
 5 & 45.373217680246100259
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

The numerical solution of this transcendental equation is $A =  45.3732176802461...$.

I obtained it via the fixed point method after having transformed the initial equation

$$a\cosh(\frac a{50})-a=20$$

(using formula $\cosh(2a)=2 \sinh^2(a)+1$) into :

$$a(1+2 \sinh^2(\frac a{100}))-a=20 \ \ \iff \ \ a \ \sinh^2(\frac a{100})=10\tag{1}$$

Function $f$ defined by $f(a)=a \sinh^2(\frac a{100})$ is increasing because its derivative $f'(a)=\sinh^2(\frac a{100})+\tfrac{a}{100} \sinh \tfrac{2a}{100}$ is positive ; as f(a) tends to $+\infty$ when $a \to \infty$, $f$ takes value $10$ for a **unique** value $A$.

Let us now transform (1) into $a=g(a)$ where $g(a):=100 \ a \ \text{asinh}\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{10}{a}}\right)$

Fixed point recurrence $a_{n+1}=g(a_n)$ with (for example) $a_0=20$ gives value $A$.

Comment: Interesting answer. Could you please let me know why you did the transformation first and not use the original function? Thanks.

Comment: A reason was to have two occurences of $a$ istead of $3$. But it was by no means compulsory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.